# elasticsearch cluster not binding each other

Tags: elasticsearch, cluster-computing

I'm trying to create an elastic search cluster, but the two computers don't see each other as clusters, I've tried a lot but it didn't

**machine-1(x.x.45.131)  elasticsearch.yml**

```
cluster.name: my-application

node.name: node-1
node.master: true
node.data: true
node.ingest: true
network.host: ["x.x.45.131"]

discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["x.x.45.131", "x.x.45.1"]
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2
```

**machine-2(x.x.45.1)  elasticsearch.yml**

```
cluster.name: my-application

node.name: node-2
node.master: false
node.data: true
node.ingest: true


network.host: ["x.x.45.1"]

discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["x.x.45.131", "x.x.45.1"]
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2

path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch

path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
```

---

**EDIT**

**ı solved**

with config below

```
node-1 (172.16.45.131)
node-2 (172.16.45.63)

elasticsearch.yml
------------------------------------------

cluster.name: my-application

node.name: node-1
node.master: true
node.data: true
node.ingest: true

network.host: 172.16.45.131
transport.port: 9300

cluster.initial_master_nodes: 
 - node-1
 - node-2



discovery.seed_hosts: 
 - 172.16.45.131
 - 172.16.45.63


path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch

path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
----------------------------------------

node-2 elasticsearch.yml

-----------------------------------------------------

cluster.name: my-application
node.name: node-2
node.master: false
node.data: true
node.ingest: true

network.host: 172.16.45.63
transport.port: 9300


discovery.seed_hosts:
  - 172.16.45.131:9300

path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
```

Comment: Which version of elasticsearch are you using?

Comment: elasticversion  7.10.0 ,lucene_version: "8.7.0"

Comment: The problem is that you have only one master node and `minimum_master_nodes: 2`. So if you set `node.master: true` on machine-2 it should work better

Comment: ı removed ```discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2``` and tried again not working.

Comment: Can you share some logs of both machines when they are starting up?

Comment: elasticsearch.log 
https://paste.laravel.io/2fce6ed0-9491-42f5-b4d4-dc2fe03b8c1a

Comment: You're actually using zen discovery which has been deprecated: `the default discovery settings are unsuitable for production use; at least one of [discovery.seed_hosts, discovery.seed_providers, cluster.initial_master_nodes] must be configured`. Check @OpsterESNinjaNishant answer which goes into the right direction

Answer (score 2):

Check the tcp port on which the nodes are running. By default elastic try to pick an available port which could be 9300 or any other free port (9300 - 9400). I would suggest you to add the following to the yml of each node so that node starts on fixed port.

```
transport.port: 9300
```

Other part would be to add bootstraping properties to yml. Since node 1 is master eligible and will be used to start the cluster for the very first time add the following as well in yml of machine-1:

```
cluster.initial_master_nodes:
  - node-1
```

Add another property which is list of master eligible nodes who will take part in master election process. Any new master eligible node in future will also go under this property. Update this in yml of both nodes:

```
discovery.seed_hosts:
  - x.x.45.131:9300
```

Following are no longer required in es-7:

```
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["x.x.45.131", "x.x.45.1"]
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2
```

Comment: which one config machine1 or machine2?

Comment: it is forbidden to set both [discovery.seed_hosts]

Comment: ı can't restart service

Comment: Can share the log

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225406/discussion-between-opster-es-ninja-nishant-and-dilo-surucu).